# Is it correct to add a tag that is inferred from a specific error message?

Tags: discussion, tags

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251298/sql-case-0-then-null) about a problem with a SQL query which didn't include any tags for a specific database, just the generic [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag.

The question did however include a specific error message:

> At least one of the result expressions in a CASE specification must be
>   an expression other than the NULL constant.

As I've seen this before in MS SQL Server (it's the error 8133 in sys.messages) I added a tag for [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server).

This was subsequently rolled back (by another use, not the OP) with the reason that what I thought was the relevant tag was irrelevant and only what the OP states is the only thing that matters.

On a side note neither MySQl or Postgresql would throw that error and a quick Google search didn't show any results suggesting anything else than MSSQL (not even Sybase which might use the same messages based on shared history).

**My question is if I were wrong to add the tag I inferred?**

And in general if this practice is fine (as the source of many error messages can be traced back to a specific system, compiler, database or whatever).

Of course I can't be 100% certain of my choice but to me it seems very likely that the specific database was indeed one in the MSSQL family.

Comment: I think you made the right call -- that error message doesn't seem to be used by anyone else.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say you were wrong, and I get why you guessed it was SQL Server but I might ask the OP in a comment to confirm what database they are targeting.  Maybe say something like _the error message appears to be from SQL Server, if so, then please tag the question as such_.

Comment: @ryanyuyu It wasn't the OP that rolled back the edit, but another user. I should have made that clear.

Comment: @bluefeet Fair enough. I just skipped that step to speed thing along as it seemed obvious that it was SQL Server.

Comment: Did you lookup the number 8133 or do you simply know?

Comment: @rene I had a vague memory of it and ran the code and got the exact same error, then I googled for it (to see if there were any matches for Sybase) and later tested with MySQL and Postgresql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are a subject matter expert (knowing the ids in the sys.message table owns my respect) on the issue raised in the question I would not hesitate to re-tag correctly, while putting some effort in providing a clear edit comment.

It might not be obvious for the OP or visitors of that question why it was retagged. To help those users an extra comment under the post to clarify why you added those tags might prevent that less seasoned users in similar technology will consider your edit as incorrect.

By the looks of it on the example question you linked to you got entangled with some other high-reps where I don't see a high tag-score in the technology used in that question. I think those users should have checked more clearly who had the best track record.

If someone still believes you did the wrong thing, leave it at the OP to clarify. It is not worth an edit/rollback war. Better use that time to write a great answer for that post.

Comment: _It is not worth an edit/rollback war. Better use that time to write a great answer for that post._ Good advice :)